# Scanner input three integers in one line

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple program that solves a quadratic equation. I have to input a b c numbers in one line, but I can't do this.

My solution:

```
1
2
-4
```

But I need that input:
`1 2 -4`

This is my solution with 3 lines input instead one line input. Sorry for my bad english.

```
package com.sircascado;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double a = sc.nextDouble();
        double b = sc.nextDouble();
        double c = sc.nextDouble();

        double d = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);

        double x1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
        double x2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);

        System.out.println(Math.ceil(x1 + x2) + " "  + Math.ceil(x1 * x2));

    }
}
```

Comment: Your program already let's you input all those 3 numbers in one line:  https://ideone.com/C76Xfo (See stdin for the input). So you already got what you want - unless you specifically want to disable the option to enter each number separately.

Comment: thank you. i separated them with enter *facepalm*

Comment: scanner.nextDouble() skips white space and that includes \t, \n.